# Drag-and-drop doesn't work in fullcalendar-5

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

The app had fullcalendar 3 version installed using jquery.
Then updated to version 5 (native) and now render () by id inside vue application.
The application also uses iscroll, fancybox.
The application is monolithic and is gradually moving to vue, that’s why a lot of things in php are being loaded simultaneously on the page.
The problem is: drag n drop used to work. It has stopped working with new implementation. Code execution does not reach handleTouchMove / handleMouseMove.
We tried making an implementation without vue on a clean page - doesn't work either.
I have no idea how to debug this to understand what the problem is, maybe there is a problem somewhere in the creation of the instance?

I disabled everything that could be disabled on the page (jquery, all unused components, menus, "glass" with tasks), but drag-and-drop still does not work.

My implementation:

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import ruLocale from "@fullcalendar/core/locales/ru";
import {DF_2_DIGIT, DF_NUMERIC, DF_SHORT} from "@constants/dateDormats";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";

/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} element
 * @param {number} height
 * @param {function} onDatesSet
 * @param {function} getEvents
 * @param {function} onEventClick
 * @return {Calendar}
 */
export default function createCalendar(element, height, {
    onDatesSet,
    getEvents,
    onEventClick,
}) {
    const calendar = new Calendar(element, {
        events: getEvents,
        datesSet: onDatesSet,
        eventClick: onEventClick,
        click: info => {
            console.log(info)  
        },
        plugins: [
            timeGridPlugin,
            interactionPlugin,
        ],
        editable: true,
        contentHeight: height,
        height,
        hiddenDays: [0, 6],
        progressiveEventRendering: true,
        nowIndicator: true,
        locale: ruLocale,
        allDaySlot: false,
        headerToolbar: false,
        dayHeaderFormat: {
            weekday: DF_SHORT,
            day: DF_NUMERIC,
        },
        scrollTime: '20:00',
        eventColor: '#fff',
        defaultTimedEventDuration: '01:00:00',
        displayEventEnd: true,
        slotLabelFormat: {
            hour: DF_NUMERIC,
            minute: DF_2_DIGIT,
            omitZeroMinute: false,
        },
        expandRows: true,
        slotMinTime: '08:00:00',
        slotMaxTime: '20:00:00',
    });
    return calendar;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean exactly by "doesn't work?"

Comment: The code goes into library methods handleMouseDown and handleTouchStart, but does not go into handleTouchMove and handleMouseMove. Accordingly, the fc-unselectable class is added to the body, but the event does not start moving

Comment: I disabled everything that could be disabled on the page (jquery, all unused components, menus, "glass" with tasks), but drag-and-drop still does not work.

Comment: Right below `contentHeight: height`, you have just a `height,`
Maybe that's messing with your implementation.